# How to filter by numbers with Node-RED REST-API

Tags: mongodb, rest, node-red

I created a small REST-API for my MongoDB with Node-RED.

This works fine: `<node-red-url>:<node-red-port>/rest/demo` shows me all entries.

I can even filter the result: Appending `?userName=demo` shows only entries where `{userName: "demo"}`.

In my DB I have some values which are numbers. Something like `{weight: 10}`. Note that this is NOT `{weight: "10"}`!

Now I want only the entries where `{weight: 10}`. But when I append `?weight=10` the transfered paramters convert `10` to `"10"`. Which has no hit, since all my `weight`-values are numbers and not strings.

Can I somehow change the appendix to filter by `weight`? Or do I have to refine my REST-logic?

//edit:
This is what my flow looks like:

`[{"id":"c4a27b53.59303","type":"mongodb in","z":"99225255.0516b8","mongodb":"7e071505.7198bc","name":"","collection":"demo","operation":"find","x":660,"y":580,"wires":[["852d2853.264698"]]},{"id":"af5a916a.08366","type":"function","z":"99225255.0516b8","name":"parseQuery","func":"msg.payload = (msg.req.query);\n\nmsg.limit = 100;\nmsg.skip = 0;\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":330,"y":580,"wires":[["c4a27b53.59303"]]},{"id":"6b0b1b4b.eb8b2c","type":"http in","z":"99225255.0516b8","name":"","url":"/rest/demo","method":"get","swaggerDoc":"","x":120,"y":580,"wires":[["af5a916a.08366"]]},{"id":"852d2853.264698","type":"http response","z":"99225255.0516b8","name":"","x":950,"y":580,"wires":[]},{"id":"7e071505.7198bc","type":"mongodb","z":"","hostname":"192.168.100.166","port":"27017","db":"training","name":"debianTraining"}]`

//edit2:
**UPDATE**

I fixed this with some more server logic:

```
if (msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('weight')) {
   msg.payload.weight = parseInt(msg.payload.weight);
}
```

I added two more cases to search for "greater than" and "lesser than":

```
if (msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('weightG')) {
   msg.payload = {"weight": {$gt: parseInt(msg.payload.weightG)}};
   delete msg.payload['weightG'];
}
if (msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('weightL')) {
   msg.payload = {"weight": {$lt: parseInt(msg.payload.weightL)}};
   delete msg.payload['weightL'];
}
```

This works fine so far.

Comment: You probably need to give us some more information about your flow here. A screen shot or the exported flow so we can see what you already have wired to what

Comment: I just edited the question and added the flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, having looked at the function node that's converting the HTTP query into the Mongo query, I don't think there is going to be a nice way to do this dynamically for an arbitrary object in Mongo.

All the HTTP query params are going to be strings so if you know of a specific field in the document that is a number you can convert just that field. e.g.

```
msg.payload = (msg.req.query);

if (msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('weight')) {
   msg.payload.weight = parseInt(msg.payload.weight)
}

msg.limit = 100;
msg.skip = 0;

return msg;
```

Comment: I have one more question, is there a way to filter for greater than? Something that is like `find({$gt: 30})`?

Comment: Ask new questions as new questions